# s3 client get_object(Range=byte_range) fails to retrieve the first bytes of an object

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, cloud-foundry, botocore

All variables fixed the below code returns an exception 'SignatureDoesNotMatch', only if it is trying to return an early byte range (e.g. bytes=0-1000). The exception does not occur, if the range is higher (e.g. bytes=400000-500000)

```
import sys
import boto3
import botocore
from boto3.session import Session, Config

def transfer(bucket, access_key, secret_key, file_name, byte_range):
    src_s3 = boto3.client('s3', 
                        verify=False,
                        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
                        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
                        config = Config(signature_version='s3v4')
                        )

    try:
        print('Now will start reading using byte_range:', byte_range)
        part_object = src_s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name, Range=byte_range)
        print('Done reading byte_range:', byte_range)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed reading byte_range:', byte_range)
        print(e)
        raise



if __name__ == "__main__":
    bucket = sys.argv[1]
    access_key = sys.argv[2]
    secret_key = sys.argv[3]
    file_name = sys.argv[4]
    byte_range = sys.argv[5]

    transfer(bucket, access_key, secret_key, file_name, byte_range)
```

Note: The issue is not reproducible on all environments, but it is consistent on the environment I am deploying to (Pivotal Cloud Foundry).

Troubleshooting, I am speculating that there is an environmental factor that confuses boto3 while calculating the signature.
Any ideas on what might be causing this exception given boto3 - Pivotal Cloud Foundry interaction?

If possible you can point me to the direction where I can understand how boto3 validates the signature.

Exception

```
2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] Traceback (most recent call last):
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] File "download_part.py", line 32, in <module>
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] transfer(bucket, access_key, secret_key, file_name, byte_range)
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] File "download_part.py", line 16, in transfer
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] part_object = src_s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name, Range=byte_range)
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.710-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 624, in _make_api_call
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.711-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    2018-12-17T14:52:07.711-05:00 [APP/TASK/7dbf1c0d/0] [ERR] botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Comment: boto3 does not *validate* the signature.  It *creates* the signature.  An invalid signature exception means the S3 service has rejected the signature, which points to a bug in your boto3/botocore version... or perhaps that your specified byte range is illogical (e.g. is a negative byte range or a space in it, though that technically would still be a boto bug.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot.. Do you know where is the code that generates the signature, I am trying to figure out what effect would a byte range have on it !!